# use DISTINCT ON Ejb-QL

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpql

is it possible to use PostgreSQL-like DISTINCT ON in EJB using named query?

o.fromDate,o.empLeaveMasterId,o.employeeInfoId, o.leavePurposeId ,o.toDate,o.createdByUserId,o.createDate,o.lastModifiedUserId,o.lastModifiedDate,o.isSystemRecord

The field describe above is my entity bean field and I want to get fromDate wise distinct record

Is it possible using namedquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how this could be possible: JPQL offers a language that can be translated into SQL for **any** database, this obviously excludes database specific keywords.

My suggestion would be to use `GROUP BY` and subqueries instead, as suggested [in the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/queries-select-lists.html):

> The `DISTINCT ON` clause is not part of the SQL standard and is sometimes considered bad style because of the potentially indeterminate nature of its results. **With judicious use of `GROUP BY` and subqueries in `FROM` the construct can be avoided**, but it is often the most convenient alternative.

Or use a native query if portability is not a concern.